# Vyatta OpenVPN fails with push-route

Tags: openvpn, vyatta, vyos

we have a router running VyattaOS 5600 5.2R5 and want to set up openvpn to access our private subnets behind that router.

Basic VPN setup was successful and connecting works as expected, but when defining push routes the tunnel interfact cannot be initialized.

config:

```
interfaces openvpn vtun0 server {
    push-route 10.10.10.0/26
    push-route 10.10.20.0/26
}
```

First investigations showed, that the openvpn executable will be called with push routes as parameters as `--push route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.192` which will be rejected by openvpn as incomplete config. Correct parameter would be `--push "route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.192"`.

Is this an issue on our configuration or on vyatta side? Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using `openvpn-option` to configure push routes.

Instead of running

```
set interfaces openvpn vtun0 server push-route 10.10.10.0/26
```

using

```
set interfaces openvpn vtun0 openvpn-option "push 'route 10.10.10.0/26'"
```

sets the route properly.